# is there a way to perform AVG on COUNT on every row in a a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table that looks like this:

| user_id | action | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | start | 2018-05-25 |
| 1 | start | 2018-05-25 |
| 2 | cancel | 2019-05-25 |
| 3 | start | 2020-05-25 |
| 4 | cancel | 2018-08-25 |
| 5 | start | 2018-02-25 |
| 6 | cancel | 2018-05-29 |
| 1 | start | 2018-05-25 |
| 1 | cancel | 2019-05-25 |
| 3 | start | 2020-05-25 |
| 1 | cancel | 2018-08-25 |
| 5 | start | 2018-02-25 |
| 6 | cancel | 2018-05-29 |
| 5 | start | 2018-05-25 |
| 4 | cancel | 2019-05-25 |
| 3 | start | 2020-05-25 |
| 2 | cancel | 2018-08-25 |
| 1 | start | 2018-02-25 |
| 6 | cancel | 2018-05-29 |

and i want to calculate the rate of starts and cancellations
i figured that i need to count the starts and cancellations and make a
average of them, but i dont know how to do that.
i found a way to count, though:

```
SELECT user_id,action,count(*) AS DQ
    FROM USERS
    WHERE action = 'cancel' 
    GROUP BY user_id,action
```

Comment: FYI, the `HAVING` is for clauses that contain aggregate functions; the above clause should be in the `WHERE` (and there should be no `HAVING`). Putting such clauses in the `HAVING` *could* have detrimental effects on the performance of your query, as the `HAVING` is actioned *after* the `GROUP BY`. For simple queries like this, the data engine is normally "clever enough" to migrate the clause to the `WHERE`, but for more complex queries you may well not be so lucky. Also `A` is an odd choice of an alias for an object called `USERS`; there are no `A`s in `USERS`.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. (Keep the same proper formatting as you already have used!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach which includes a total

```
Select [User_id]= coalesce(left([User_id],10),'Total')
      ,[Start]  = avg(case when [Action]='start'  then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Cancel] = avg(case when [Action]='cancel' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Cnt]    = count(*)
 From YourTable
 Group By Grouping Sets ( ([User_id])
                          ,()
                        )
```

**Results**

```
User_ID   Start     Cancel
1         0.666666  0.333333
2         0.000000  1.000000
3         1.000000  0.000000
4         0.000000  1.000000
5         1.000000  0.000000
6         0.000000  1.000000
Total     0.526315  0.473684
```

Comment: Could you please explain why did you used the "case" clause?

Comment: @Aby_g It is a conditional aggregation.   Honestly, I was guessing on the desired output.   The Grouping Sets (or even the GROUP BY)   is optional.

Comment: @Aby_g If no case expression, there would be no segregation between start/cancel